# Minkowski for series

Tags: lp-spaces

Consider $g=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mid f_i\mid$ where $(f_i)$ are functions on $L^p(R^n)$. I know that for every $f$ and $g$ in $L^p(R^n)$, where $p\geq 1$, we have that $\mid f+g \mid_p \leq \mid f\mid _p + \mid g\mid _p$ where $\mid . \mid_p$ is the $L^p(R^n)$ norm. Is it true that : 
$$\mid g \mid_p \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mid f_i \mid _p$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from Fatou's Lemma and Minkowski's inequality for finite sums. If $g_N$ is the $n-$the partial sum of $\sum |f_i|$ then $(\int |g|^{p})^{1/p} \leq \lim \inf_{N \to \infty} (\int |g_N|^{p})^{1/p} \leq \sum \|f_i\|_p$.

Comment: Can you please remind me what is the precise theorem of Fatou ?

Comment: Fatou's Lemma says that $\int \lim \inf f_n d\mu \leq \lim \inf \int f_n d\mu$ whenever $f_n$'s are non-negative measurable functions. @Dicordi

Comment: and so here, $\lim \inf g_N=g$ true ?

Comment: Yes, when  the limit exists, $\lim \inf$ is same as the limit. @Dicordi